# Laravel 5 - Error in Server - View inside a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a bug that i cant solve, in my machine everything works fine, however when i upload laravel into a server, if i have a view inside a view laravel pops up an error:

```
    InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
    View [articles.welcome] not found.
```

Steps i used to put up laravel in the server:
1 - Zip the entire application.
2 - SSH the server, create a folder "laravel" and point the "public_html" to "laravel/public" folder.
3 - link database settings in .env file.

I have checked if the files exist in the directory, and they exist.

Useful links to my website:
[My Error](http://brunomartins.pro)
[Only one view, no errors.(Real data)](http://brunomartins.pro/blog)

In my machine i installed laravel with composer and have XAMP to serve a  localhost.
The server runs on CPanel.

ANSWER!!

Turns out linux paths are case sensitive, and since i was returning a view like this

```
return view('articles.welcome')
```

Laravel mapped the path to resources/views/articles, but my folder was "Articles".

```
return view('Articles.welcome')
```

It seems windows paths are not case sensitive.

Comment: composer dump-autoload

Comment: if you're already having ssh why not just git deploy ?? it's so much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this file (as per your linked stacktrace) `/home/brunomart/laravel/resources/views/articles/welcome.blade.php` exist?

Before you answer "yes". Are you sure? SSH into your server, and type something like:

`ls /home/brunomart/laravel/resources/views/articles/welcome.blade.php`

to prove that it indeed does exist. Past that, trying running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: For leading me in the right direction, im going to accept your answer, it seems windows paths are not case sensitive, since linux paths is case sensive i had to map my return view to "Articles". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

run this command

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer update
```

Comment: Never ever run `composer update` in a production environment! In a production environment always run `composer install`. http://www.dev-metal.com/difference-composer-install-composer-update/